# Is a nonzero subalgebra $A$ of a finite dimensional division algebra $D$ itself a division algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**In a finite dimensional unital algebra $A$, a right inverse of an element is automatically also a left inverse; that is, $ab = 1$ implies $ba = 1$.**
‎
‎

The discussion in above shows, in particular, that finite dimensional unital algebras enjoy a rather special property: **every nonzero element is either invertible or a zero divisor**.

> Can you explain this statement "every nonzero element is either invertible or a zero divisor"?
>
> Is a nonzero subalgebra $A$ of a finite dimensional division algebra $D$  itself a division algebra?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over the field $F$. For $a\in A$, consider the map
$$
L_a\colon A\to A,\quad L_a(x)=ax
$$
This is $F$-linear. If $a$ is not right invertible, then $L_a$ is not surjective, so it is neither injective; therefore there exists $b\in A$, $b\ne0$, with $ab=0$ (so $a$ is a left zero divisor).

Similarly, if $a$ is not left invertible, then $a$ is a right zero divisor, that is, $ca=0$ for some $c\ne 0$.

If $a$ is right invertible, then it is not a right zero divisor: if $ca=0$ and $b$ is the right inverse for $a$, then $0=(ca)b=c(ab)=c$. Therefore $a$ must be also left invertible. Similarly, from $a$ left invertible, we deduce $a$ is right invertible.

So we have proved the statement that, if $a$ is not a (left or right) zero divisor, then $a$ is invertible.

---

Suppose $A$ is a subalgebra of a finite dimensional division algebra $D$ over $F$. Take $a\in A$, $a\ne0$. Can $a$ be a zero divisor? What can you conclude from the above?